# Error When Creating an Unbounded Child Partition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am running Postgres 12 and following examples from a book titled *PostgreSQL: Up and Running* published by O'Reilly Media. I am trying to create a partitioned table group like so:

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
    log_id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    user_name varchar(50),
    description text,
    log_ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
) PARTITION BY RANGE (log_ts);
```

The child partition is:

```
CREATE TABLE logs_gt_2011 PARTITION OF logs
FOR VALUES FROM ('2012-1-1') TO (unbounded);
```

This returns the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use column reference in partition bound expression
LINE 2: for values from ('2012-1-1') to (unbounded);
```

which makes it seem like it thinks `unbounded` is a column name. I thought `unbounded` was a Postgres keyword. Can you help me figure out the correct way to create this child partition?

I am running Postgres on a Windows 10 machine, from Powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the book gets it from, but according [to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html), that should be `maxvalue`:

> The special values MINVALUE and MAXVALUE may be used when creating a range partition to indicate that there is no lower or upper bound on the column's value

```
CREATE TABLE logs_gt_2011 PARTITION OF logs
FOR VALUES FROM ('2012-01-01') TO (maxvalue);
```